# `! Dimension too large` error using `kik-android` template

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes, dimensions

I am using this template (`kik-android.cls`, now `whatsapp.cls`):

[Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/239511#239511)

as a guide to write a document using `pdflatex` mode. Since I am on `pdflatex` I deleted `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{DroidSans}`.

Now I want to change the dimensions of the document since I have to print it on a `A4` paper. So I change the line:

```
\usepackage[top=.55in,bottom=.55in,right=.015in,left=.015in,paperwidth=2.308in,paperheight=4.103in]{geometry}
```

to

```
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
```

and a lot of errors appeared.

## With errors

[In chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53617071#53617071) some users kindly told me that a change from a small size to a large paper size may cause problems with `tikzpicture`.

This is `whatsapp.cls`:

```
% whatsapp.cls
%   taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/239511#239511
%   by Brian Jacobs (fixes by Maximilian Noethe).
%   April 10, 2018
%

\ProvidesClass{whatsapp}

% Start with article. Eventually this should be removed,
% because I'm not actually using it for much of anything
\LoadClass{article}

% Load all necessary packages
\usepackage{varwidth}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


% Set up the page
%\usepackage[top=.55in,bottom=.55in,right=.015in,left=.015in,paperwidth=2.308in,paperheight=4.103in]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

% Style the page
\pagestyle{empty}
%\setmainfont{DroidSans}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Color Definitions
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundgray}{RGB}{238,238,238}
\definecolor{linegray}{RGB}{212,212,212}
\definecolor{circgray}{RGB}{199,199,199}
\definecolor{circdarkgray}{RGB}{117,117,117}
\definecolor{arrowgray}{RGB}{107,107,107}
\definecolor{msggreen}{RGB}{185,224,97}
\definecolor{androidgray}{RGB}{191,191,191}
\definecolor{repwiregreen}{RGB}{71,146,53}
\definecolor{kikblue}{RGB}{103,142,233}
\definecolor{kiktimepalegray}{RGB}{158,169,184}
\definecolor{kiktimedarkgray}{RGB}{122,133,151}

% Customization Flags
\def\@hours{12}
\def\@minutes{11}
\def\@partnerName{Sample Name}

% Macros to draw the background
\def\@statusbar#1{%
  \def\c{androidgray}
  \fill[\c]
    let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
      (\x1 - .42in - #1in, \y1 - 0.0415in - #1in) rectangle (\x1 - .43in -#1in, \y1 - 0.1409 in);
}

% Background Macro
\def\@drawBackground{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    % Background
    \fill[backgroundgray] (current page.north east) rectangle (current page.south west);

    \fill[black]
    (current page.south west) -- (current page.south east) --++(0,1in) -| (current page.south west) -- cycle;
    \fill[green]
    let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
    let \p2 = (current page.north west) in
    (\p1,\y1 - 0.1667in) rectangle (\x2,\y2 - .5289in);
    \fill[white]
    let \p1 = (current page.south east) in
    let \p2 = (current page.south west) in
    (\x1,\y1 + 0.3141in) rectangle (\x2,\y2 + .6090in);
    \draw[thick,linegray]
    let \p1 = (current page.south east) in
    let \p2 = (current page.south west) in
    (\x1,\y1 + .6090in) -- (\x2,\y2 + .6090in);

    % Kik Top bar decorations

      % Name
    \draw
      let \p1 = (current page.north west) in
        (\x1 + .4647in, \y1 - .3481in) node[anchor=west] {\@partnerName};

      % Arrow
    \draw[thick,circdarkgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.north west) in
        (\x1 + .1314in, \y1 - .3397in) -- (\x1 + .2179in , \y1 - .3397in);
    \draw[thick,circdarkgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.north west) in
        (\x1 + .1795in, \y1 - .2981in) -- (\x1 + .1314in, \y1 - .3397in) --
        (\x1 + .1795in, \y1 - .3846in);

    % Kik Bottom Bar Decorations

    % Android Bottom Bar Decorations
    % Home
    \draw[very thick,androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south) in
        (\x1 - .1186in, \y1 + .08974in) -- (\x1 + .1186in, \y1 + .08974in) -- 
        (\x1 + .1186in, \y1 + .1795in)  -- (\x1, \y1 + .2115in) -- 
        (\x1 - .1186in, \y1 + .1795in) -- cycle;

    % Pages
    \draw[very thick,androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south east) in
        (\x1 - .4391in, \y1 + .1058in) rectangle (\x1 - .6026in, \y1 + .1795in);
    \draw[very thick,androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south east) in
        (\x1 - .3974in, \y1 + .1346in) -- (\x1 - .3974in, \y1 + .2219in) --
        (\x1 - .5545in, \y1 + .2219in);

    % Back arrow
    \draw[very thick,androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south west) in
        (\x1 + .4199in, \y1 + 0.1635in) -- (\x1 + .5833in, \y1 + 0.1635in) to[bend left=90]
        (\x1 + .5833in, \y1 + .0993in) -- (\x1 + .5032in, \y1 + .0993in);
    \draw[very thick,androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south west) in
        (\x1 + .4487in, \y1 + .1987in) -- (\x1 + .4199in, \y1 + .1635in) -- (\x1 + .4487in, \y1 + .1282in);

  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Make the background appear on every page
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\@drawBackground}


% Commands for use by the user.
\def\setPartnerName#1{
  \def\@partnerName{#1}
}

\def\setPartnerPic#1{
  \def\@partnerPic{#1}
}

\def\setHours#1{
  \def\@hours{#1}
}

\def\setMinutes#1{
  \def\@minutes{#1}
}

\def\me#1{
  \hphantom{.}\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[anchor=north east,rectangle,rounded corners=2,fill=msggreen, scale=0.75,draw=circgray] {
      \hspace{.1in}\begin{varwidth}{1.5in}
        \vphantom{.}
        \raggedright #1\\
        \tiny \color{msggreen}.
      \end{varwidth}
      \hspace{.1in}%
    };
    \fill[msggreen] (-0.01in,-0.06in) -- (0.06in,-0.12in) -- (-0.01in,-0.18in) -- cycle;
    \draw[circgray] (0,-0.06in) -- (0.06in,-0.12in) -- (0in,-0.18in);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{.05in}\\
}

\def\you#1{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \ifdefined\@partnerPic
    \draw (-.6,-.3) node[scale=1.825,circle, path picture={
        \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
          \includegraphics[width=.24in]{\@partnerPic}
        };
      }
    ] {};
    \else\fill[black] (-.6,-.3) circle (.12in);\fi
    \draw (0,0) node[anchor=north west,rectangle,rounded corners=2,fill=white, scale=0.75,draw=linegray] {
      \hspace{.1in}\begin{varwidth}[c]{1.5in}
        \vphantom{.}
        \raggedright #1\\
        \tiny \color{white}.
      \end{varwidth}
      \hspace{.1in}
    };
    \fill[white] (0.01in,-0.06in) -- (-0.06in,-0.12in) -- (0.01in,-0.18in) -- cycle;
    \draw[linegray] (0,-0.06in) -- (-0.06in,-0.12in) -- (0in,-0.18in);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{.05in}\\
}

\def\time#1#2{
  \hphantom{.}\hfil\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[scale=.65] {\color{kiktimepalegray}#1 \color{kiktimedarkgray}@ #2};
  \end{tikzpicture}\hfil\\
}
```

and this is `Guia.tex`:

```
\documentclass{whatsapp}

\setPartnerName{Dave Johnson}
%\setPartnerPic{Man.jpg}
\setHours{12}
\setMinutes{11}

\begin{document}
    \you{Knock knock}
    \me{Who's there?}
    \you{Canoe}
    \me{Canoe who?}
    \you{Canoe help me with my homework?}
    \time{Fri}{12:03 PM}
    \you{...please. I'm gonna fail calculus. :-(}
    \me{...}
\end{document}
```

## Without errors

Since the problem is the paper size, I realize that deleting lines 57-127 (the `Background` part) it compiles without errors:

[image: Without errors]

So the problem is around the `Background` section of the `whatsapp` class.

Can anyone help me discovering the error(s)?

**EDIT** Since some users compile `Guia.tex` using `whatsapp.cls` without errors I add the log file after one compilaton of `Guia.tex`: https://pastebin.com/H1Q5qMzi (sorry for the link but the log was too long.)

Comment: On my machine it compiles without errors. What do I need to change to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thank you for your feedback! Did you use `whatsapp.cls`? I just copied it and it gives me errors. I will add the log file for clarification.

Comment: Yes, I copied the snippet in your code that starts with `% whatsapp.cls` and called it `whatsapp.cls`. Of course, I made sure that it gets loaded. I get zillions of warnings but no errors. I compile with pdflatex.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat did you write `whatsapp.cls` on a editor and save it as `.cls`? And created a `.tex` and copied the `Guia.tex` on the same folder directory? I have no idea why you have no errors. Do you have uncommented `[a4paper]{geometry}` on line 23, and commented the line 22?

Comment: Yes. I did not call the file `Guia.tex` but this shouldn't matter. Everything else as you say.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have no idea, sorry. Did you read the log file? Perhaps you (or other users) can predict what's going on here.

Comment: This is *really* weird: if I compile a "naked" TeX file, i.e. create a TeX file which does not have an aux file, I do reproduce the error. However, I ignore it (hit return) and compile again, the error disappears. So that means that when the overlay coordinates are not yet settled, you get the error, but once they settle, the dimensions are OK.

Comment: Please also note that this class has a wealth of hard-code values which seem to be chosen to harmonize with `\usepackage[top=.55in,bottom=.55in,right=.015in,left=.015in,paperwidth=2.308in,paperheight=4.103in]{geometry}`. IMHO it would have been much cleaner if the authors would load `tikzpagenodes` and use it instead of using these hard-coded dimensions.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat could you detail how you do get the "I ignore it (hit return) and compile again", please? I also think that the values are very forced and not automated, but I want to create a new template for an exercise guide, which you can watch an outline here and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy32E.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1mEH.png).

Comment: I was not trying to suggest that you hit return. Rather, I think you should try to write a cleaner class file, which uses `tikzpagenodes`. BTW, there is an error on the headlines of the exercise guide, "make" should probably read "bake". ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I started to write a completely new document ;). You can start helping me here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529696/how-to-place-a-draw-near-the-page-number-using-tikzpicture